# Intent to Vacate apartment before 30 days, do I need to be there for 30 days?

Tags: residential-lease

I live in Alabama and I originally signed a one year lease and that expired and have been living month to month for the past 13 or so months.  I have a job offer confirmed June 17 and want to vacate early.  The new job is over 100 miles away.  I realize I need to do a 30 day intent to vacate letter, but of course I won't be here since I will be living somewhere else because of my new job.

I plan to give my landlord my "30 day notice" to leave June 3, which means I'm obligated up to July 3.  My question is a general one, couldn't I just give the keys to the landlord June 14 and tell the property manager that I intend to pay rent up to July 3?  Do I actually physically need to be here until July 3?

Answer (score 3):

No, you don't need to physically be there. The landlord may be required to refund some rent if they rent it out early. They may also not be available for a walk through until your last day, so you may need to show back up.

Technically if you pay rent for the month the apartment is yours until July 3. You can turn the keys in early.

Comment: Good answer (+1). In fact, the OP's lease surely has language reflecting that his duties are in terms of timely payment, return of keys upon vacating the unit, peaceful use/enjoyment of premises, etc., but no requirement of actually living in the unit.